# Response does not include associations

Tags: java, hibernate, rest, spring-boot, jpa

I am developing a Spring Boot rest api.
I have got the following two Hibernate entities:

**OrderEntity**

```
@Table(name = "orders")
@Getter
@Setter
public @Entity class OrderEntity extends AbstractPersistable<Long> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1780337491454957180L;

    @Column(name = "order_number")
    @Setter(value = AccessLevel.NONE)
    private String orderId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
    private UserEntity user;

    @Digits(integer = 10, fraction = 2)
    @Column(name = "total_amount")
    @Range(min = 0, message = "The total amount must be greater or equals to zero.")
    private BigDecimal totalAmount = BigDecimal.ZERO;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "order", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<OrderDetailEntity> items = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(nullable = false, name = "card_details_id")
    private CardDetailsEntity card;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(nullable = false, name = "shipping_address_id")
    private AddressEntity shippingAddress;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(nullable = true, name = "billing_address_id")
    private AddressEntity billingAddress;

    @Column(name = "one_address", columnDefinition = "BOOLEAN")
    private boolean oneAddress;

    public void addOrderDetail(OrderDetailEntity detail) {
        items.add(detail);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        buffer.append(orderId).append(" (").append(totalAmount).append(") ");
        items.forEach(i -> buffer.append(i.getProduct().getName()).append("; qty: ").append(i.getQuantity())
                .append("; amount: ").append(i.getTotalAmount()).append(System.lineSeparator()));
        return buffer.append("]").toString();
    }

    public void setOrderId(UUID uuid) {
        orderId = uuid.toString();
    }
}
```

and:

**OrderDetailEntity**

```
@Table(name = "order_detail")
@Getter @Setter
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PUBLIC)
public @Entity class OrderDetailEntity extends AbstractPersistable<Long> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8128749778263610480L;

    @Column(name = "quantity")
    private Integer quantity;

    @Digits(integer = 10, fraction = 2)
    @Column(name = "total_amount")
    @Range(min = 0, message = "The total amount must be greater or equals to zero.")
    private BigDecimal totalAmount = BigDecimal.ZERO;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "order_id")
    @JsonBackReference
    private OrderEntity order;

    @OneToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_id")
    private ProductEntity product;
}
```

Also I have written a spring data jpa **repository** for orders and order details:

```
@Repository
public interface OrderRepository extends JpaRepository<OrderEntity, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT o FROM OrderEntity o LEFT JOIN FETCH o.items i WHERE o.user.email = ?1")
    List<OrderEntity> findOrdersByUser(String email);
}

@Repository
public interface OrderDetailRepository extends JpaRepository<OrderDetailEntity, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT d FROM OrderDetailEntity d LEFT JOIN FETCH d.order o WHERE o.orderId = ?1")
    List<OrderDetailEntity> findOrderItemsByUser(String orderId);
}
```

The **services**:

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public List<OrderDetailEntity> getOrderItems(final long userId, final String orderId) {
    String currentUser = SecurityUtil.getCurrentUserEmail();
    List<OrderDetailEntity> orderDetails = userService.findOneByEmail(currentUser)
        .filter(user -> user.getId() == userId)
        .map(user -> {
            return orderDetailRepository.findOrderItemsByUser(orderId);
        }).orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException());

    return orderDetails;
}

@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public List<OrderEntity> getOrders(final long userId) {
    String currentUser = SecurityUtil.getCurrentUserEmail();
    List<OrderEntity> orders = userService.findOneByEmail(currentUser)
        .filter(user -> user.getId() == userId)
        .map(user -> {
            return orderRepository.findOrdersByUser(user.getEmail());
        }).orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException());
    return orders;
}
```

And the **controller** methods (end-points):

```
@GetMapping("/users/{userId}/orders")
public List<OrderEntity> getOrders(@PathVariable Long userId) {
    return orderService.getOrders(userId);
}

@GetMapping("/users/{userId}/orders/{orderId}")
public List<OrderDetailEntity> getOrderItems(@PathVariable Long userId, @PathVariable String orderId) {
    return orderService.getOrderItems(userId, orderId);
}
```

In both responses, some associations are not included in.
I better example:

If I fire the following request:

```
curl -X GET "http://localhost:8080/users/1/orders/d329cba4-5ead-4f5d-9663-557e99ab46f1"
```

I received the following result:

```
[ {
  "quantity" : 1,
  "totalAmount" : 105.00,
  "new" : false
} ]
```

which does not include the `product` reference, but only the fields quantity and `totalAmount`.

Also, if I fire the following request:

```
curl -X GET "http://localhost:8080/users/1/orders"

[ {
  "created" : "2018-05-12T14:02:00",
  "orderId" : "d329cba4-5ead-4f5d-9663-557e99ab46f1",
  "totalAmount" : 105.00,
  "card" : {
    "created" : "2018-05-12T14:02:00",
    "brand" : "American Express",
    "expMonth" : 2,
    "expYear" : 2022,
    "last4" : "0005",
    "new" : false,
    "links" : [ ],
    "content" : [ ],
    "links" : [ ]
  },
  "shippingAddress" : {
    "modified" : "2018-05-12T14:02:00",
    "created" : "2018-05-12T14:02:00",
    "streetAddress" : "test",
    "country" : "Netherlands",
    "city" : "test",
    "state" : "test",
    "postalCode" : "test",
    "new" : false,
    "links" : [ ],
    "content" : [ ],
    "links" : [ ]
  },
  "billingAddress" : {
    "modified" : "2018-05-12T14:02:00",
    "created" : "2018-05-12T14:02:00",
    "streetAddress" : "test",
    "country" : "Netherlands",
    "city" : "test",
    "state" : "test",
    "postalCode" : "test",
    "new" : false,
    "links" : [ ],
    "content" : [ ],
    "links" : [ ]
  },
  "oneAddress" : true,
  "new" : false
} ]
```

This response does not contain the `items` field which I also need to get from the response, even if there are items associated with any order.
What is the problem? Why the above quoted fields are not included in the response?

Thank you

**EDIT**

I tried to add in `OrderDetailEntity` the following field:

```
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "address_id")
private AddressEntity address;
```

This is then correctly serialized:

```
curl  -X GET "http://localhost:8080/users/1/orders/2f8254e6-b04a-4fb0-baae-cb27fcd11a87"

[ {
  "quantity" : 1,
  "totalAmount" : 10.99,
  "address" : {
    "streetAddress" : "aa",
    "country" : "Netherlands",
    "city" : "aa",
    "state" : "a",
    "postalCode" : "a",
    "modified" : "2018-05-12T18:49:48",
    "created" : "2018-05-12T18:49:48",
    "new" : false,
    "links" : [ ],
    "content" : [ ],
    "links" : [ ]
  },
  "id" : 8,
  "new" : false
```

But ProductEntity is not serialized. Following are the two entities. I cannot understand the difference. Maybe ProductEntity contains other associations (and AddressEntity not), that could affect somehow the serialization then?

**ProductEntity**

```
@Table(name = "product")
@Getter @Setter
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PUBLIC) @AllArgsConstructor
public @Entity class ProductEntity extends AbstractPersistable<Long> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5077959382034660336L;

    @NotEmpty
    @Column(name = "product_name", length = 254)
    private String name;

    @NotEmpty
    @Column(name = "product_description", length = 254)
    private String description;

    @Digits(integer = 12, fraction = 2)
    @Column(name = "product_price")
    @Range(min = 0, message = "The price must be greater or equals to 0.")
    private BigDecimal price;

    @NotEmpty
    @Column(name = "image_url", length = 254)
    private String imageUrl;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_category_id")
    @JsonBackReference
    @JsonIgnore
    private CategoryEntity category;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "product", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @BatchSize(size = 10)
    @OrderBy
    private SortedSet<ProductThumbnailEntity> thumbnails;

    public ProductEntity(Long id) {
        this.setId(id);
    }

    public ProductEntity(String name, String description, BigDecimal price) {
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.price = price;
    }
}
```

**AddressEntity**

```
@Table(name = "address")
@Getter @Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
@AllArgsConstructor
public @Entity class AddressEntity extends AbstractEntity<Long> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1544232699919709073L;

    @Size(max = 254)@Column(name = "street_address")
    private String streetAddress;

    @Size(max = 50)
    private String country;

    @Size(max = 40)
    private String city;

    @Size(max = 100)
    private String state;

    @Size(max = 16) @Column(name = "postal_code")
    private String postalCode;
}
```

Comment: have you added `@JsonIgnore` on items getter?

Comment: @emotionlessbananas I have tried adding JsonIgnore to the getter method but with no luck. Anyway why? JsonIgnore? I wanna retrieve items, not ignore them

Comment: You can set fetch type to be eager for set of items field in OrderEntity so that they  are fetched along with orders.

Comment: @AbhayJain it does not work :/ same result

Comment: You don't need to do a left join in the query. Change your query to "SELECT o FROM OrderEntity o WHERE o.user.email = ?1"

Comment: @AbhayJain still no luck

Comment: I am not 100% sure as I have not used @JsonBackReference till now. But maybe its has something to do with your issue. Can you check http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-bidirectional-relationships-and-infinite-recursion and the comments as well in this post if it helps?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170914/discussion-between-shaunyl-and-abhay-jain).